# Classification modeling with duplicated customer_id and multiple spending categories

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-cleaning

I am trying to predict if a customer will convert to premium shoppers. The dataset looks as below:

```
customer_id  category  sales   conversion
1234           1        18       converted
1234           2        24       converted
1568           2        49       not converted
1568           6        12       not converted
1568           1        17       not converted
```

I am trying to predict if a customer will convert or not using 1)logistic regression 2) light GBM. However, usually the customer id is unique, corresponding with multiple spending information.

For my case, I cannot pivot category because there are 30 categories, but I am afraid duplicated customer_id will impact my final model prediction.

1. How do I deal with the category code?
2. How do I deal with the duplicate of customer_id? Any good model that can handle this?